# Objective-C concurrency processing

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I've got class:

```
ClassX.m

@property (assign) BOOL wasProcessed;

-(void) methodA { //<- this can be called many times in short period of time
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self methodB];
    });
}

- (void) methodB {
    if (!self.wasProcessed) {
        self.wasProcessed = YES;

        //... some code
    }
}
```

Since dispatch_async is used so a few calls to methodB can be processed concurrently at the same time and following code needs to be atomic:

```
if (!self.wasProcessed) {
self.wasProcessed = YES; //e.g two calls can enter here before setting YES and it would be bad because I want to process it only one time
```

How can those 2 lines be made atomic (checking and setting variable)? I dont want to make atomic code that is after "self.wasProcessed = YES;" so moving whole if to @synchronize(self) won't be good solution. If there is anything wrong with my thinking please point it out as I'm not very experienced in those topics, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try @synchronized.  While the enclosed code is being executed on a thread, it will block other threads from executing it.

```
- (void) methodB {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!self.wasProcessed) {
            self.wasProcessed = YES;

            //... some code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought there will be some issues with that solution but it seems to work correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) methodA {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(){
            [self methodB];
        }];
    });
}
```

Your's methodB will be only called in main thread, so it will be never performed simultaneously.

Comment: This will work, but is unnecessarily onerous, as it will interlock all background threads with the main thread with respect to calling this method. Incidentally, for almost all cases, `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` and `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ...]` are equivalent, therefore this would be redundant. (Yes, there is very subtle difference in their semantics, but not one that's going to make a difference here.)

Comment: Agree. I wasn't know about dispatch_async and dispatch_get_main_queue and thinked that this is some user's functions :) So if dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...) and [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ...] do same thing then 'methodB' don't need synchronization.